# Batch script to take the output of a command and create a variable out of it?

Tags: command-line, batch, environment-variables, cmd.exe

For example, I want to search for a file

where /r C:\ "myfile.txt"

and then make the output of that command which would be the file path to "myfile.txt" a variable I choose,

So then the path to that file is now a variable so I could do echo %variable% and it would print the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
c:\> for /?
```

... will list how `for` works, look for the line

```
 FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (`command`) DO command [command-parameters]
```

and read about it.

Now note that %variable is LOCAL to `for` so you need to have e.g. `set F=%variable` within `command`

```
C:\> for /F "usebackq" %v in (`echo Check-it-out`) do @ set F=%v
C:\> echo To do: %F%
```

will print 
`To do: Check-it-out`

Comment: Additional comment: If you do not have any specific reason to restrict yourself to CMD.EXE, then a peek into more capable scripting languages might be worthwhile. PowerShell is one, and there is many more of them...