# SHORT_HASH=git rev-parse --short HEAD in Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I'd do the following in Linux with Bash:

```
SHORT_HASH=git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

I can't find a single post explaining how to do this in Windows in the `cmd`?

Comment: You mean to assign the output of a command to a variable? Type `for /?` into a command prompt window and particularly look for the `/F` option: `for /F "delims=" %I in ('git rev-parse --short HEAD') do set "SHORT_HASH=%I"`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch script to take the output of a command and create a variable out of it?](https://superuser.com/questions/787487/batch-script-to-take-the-output-of-a-command-and-create-a-variable-out-of-it)